# will the acceleration of a freely falling body having rotional motion be differet from g?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, kinematics

A disk is falling freely vertically rotating on its on axis while doing so. Will the acceleration of the body be different from 'g'?

Comment: What do you think, and why?

Comment: I think that it should be different.! But I am not certain what exactly should be the acceleration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what axis it is rotating around.

The formula for gravitation is like this
$$F_G = G\frac{m_{disk} m_{earth}}{d²}$$
Newton further says
$$F_G = m_{disk} g$$
so that
$$g=\frac{F_G}{m_{disk}}=G\frac{ m_{earth}}{d²}$$

As you can see, g depends on two variables $m_{earth}$ and $d²$.
The only one that the disk can really change is $d$, which is the distance from the center of gravity of earth to the center of gravity of the disk.

If that disk rotates around **an axis that does not go through its center of gravity** and if **this axis is not parallel to its direction of motion**, the rotation will move the center of gravity of the disk around in a way that changes $d$ and therefore $g$

Comment: So will the value of g increase?

Comment: @KritikaWaghmare the rotation will move the center of gravity around the axis of the rotation, cause $d$ and thus $g$ to oscillate.  $g$ will increase a little, then decrease a little,... at the end of one full revolution it will have the same value again. (given that the entire disk did not move closer towards earth as a whole).

Comment: And what if it moves closer towards the earth? It is a free fall condition.

Comment: @KritikaWaghmare please _take a look at the formula_ it will tell you what happens to $g$ if $d$ is decreased. But your insufficiently terms make it impossible to tell how $d$ behaves. A rotation can very well dominate the entire motion of the disk, reversing the free fall. You should properly define the rotation, which in term allows you to determine its influence on $d$ hence answering your question.

Comment: Lets not complicate it. Its a simple disk having conspicuous mass which is freely falling performing rotations. You can imagine it as a roll of massless thread uncoiling itself.

Comment: @KritikaWaghmare this is covered by my answer which explains the case of how the rotation can have an influence in $g$ if these special circumstances are not yours, then the rotation has no influence..

Answer (score 0):

For a sufficiently small rigid disk, the answer is effectively no. When the disk is vertical (perpendicular to the surface of the gravitational body) I believe there would be a small tidal effect that would be absent when the disk is horizontal (parallel to the surface) but that effect would be extremely tiny unless you were talking about, say, an enormous disk in orbit.

Comment: What if the body is having considerable mass. Not enormous!